# Control browser from CLI or Java program

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, browser, webbrowser-control

I want to start, stop, fetch the current active tab and stop the session of a browser programmatically **WITHOUT USING SELENIUM**. This can be either a java program or CLI commands. Please help

Comment: Could you be more specific?  What information do you want to fetch about the tab?  What is the difference between "stop" and "stop the session"?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco. We just want to display the URL of the currently active tab. And stop the session, which means we have to reset the browser state to default. And stop the browser will just shut down the browser.

Comment: Any particular reason why you won't use Selenium? It seems a well established tool for these kinds of applications, and without it you will essentially be opting for one of the many alternative libraries which serve the same purpose

Comment: Basically it is a challenge from a hiring company. So it is something like a brainstorming challenge